# Load controls on runtime based on selection

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm new to XAML and I have a case where I need to change controls based on a selection on a combobox with templates.

For example, let's say that a user selects a template that requires a day of week and a time range that something will be available. I would like that, on the moment of the selection, the control with the information needed get build on the screen and that the bindings get to work as well.

Can someone give me a hint or indicate an article with an elegant way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is a ContentControl and DataTemplates. You use the selected item of the ComboBox to change ContentTemplate of the Content Control.

You question mentions binding so I will assume you understand the MVVM pattern.

As an example, lets use MyModel1 as the Model

```
public class MyModel1
{
    private Collection<string> values;
    public Collection<string> Values { get { return values ?? (values = new Collection<string> { "One", "Two" }); } }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

And MyViewModel as the ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Model = new MyModel1();
    }
    public MyModel1 Model { get; set; }
}
```

And the code behind does nothing but instantiate the ViewModel.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

All three are very simple classes. The fun comes in the Xaml which is

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow._20893945.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:StackOverflow._20893945" 
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyModel1Template1" DataType="{x:Type this:MyModel1}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Template 1"></TextBlock>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Field1}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyModel1Template2" DataType="{x:Type this:MyModel1}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Template 2"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Field2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="2">
            <ComboBox x:Name="TypeSelector">
                <system:String>Template 1</system:String>
                <system:String>Template 2</system:String>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Model}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TypeSelector, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Template 2">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyModel1Template2}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyModel1Template1}" />
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The notable points of the view are

1. The DataContext is initialised on the Window element, allowing for auto-complete on our binding expressions
2. The definition of 2 template to display 2 different views of the data.
3. The ComboBox is populated with a list of strings and has a default selection of the first element.
4. The ContentControl has its content bound to the Model exposed via the ViewModel
5. The default DataTemplate is the first template with a ComboBox.
6. The Trigger in the ContentControl's style will change the ContentTemplate if the SelectedItem of the ComboBox is changed to 'Template 2'

Implied facts are

1. If the SelectedItem changes back to 'Template 1', the style will revert the the ContentTemplate back to the default, ie MyModel1Template1
2. If there were a need for 3 separate displays, create another DataTemplate, add a string to the ComboBox and add another DataTrigger.

*NOTE: This is the complete source to my example. Create a new C#/WPF project with the same classes and past the code in. It should work.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems exactly what I need, Mark, gonna try it. Thanks!